# copying objects/files from one AWS s3 bucket to another without subfolder path from the source bucket

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I have a s3 bucket with files like this :

```
Bucket1/subfolderA/subfolderB/File1.txt,
Bucket1/subfolderA/subfolderB/File2.txt,
Bucket1/subfolderA/subfolderB/File3.Pdf.
```

I want to copy only .txt files from Bucket1 to a another bucket like this-

```
Bucket2/subfolderC/File1.txt,
Bucket2/subfolderC/File2.txt
```

when I run this command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://Bucket1/ s3://Bucket2/subfolderC/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.txt"
```

I get:

```
Bucket2/subfolderC/subfolderA/subfolderB/File1.txt,
Bucket2/subfolderC/subfolderA/subfolderB/File2.txt
```

So, I basically want to exclude the file path when copying these .txt files into the new bucket. I just need all the .txt files from all the subfolders in the source bucket(Bucket1) to move to a single subfolder in the destination bucket(Bucket2).
Also, I am using a Linux machine.

please let me know the best way to do this.

Comment: You might have to do this file by file, to control the target key.

Comment: @jarmod - so it is actually a huge bucket with data in TB and I have over 500 subfolders  with multiple files in them, I want to select only certain files from these subfolders and save it in a single subfolder inside the destination bucket. Is there any way, maybe using some kind of script to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can write a shell script or Python script (using boto3) to enumerate the objects that you want to copy and then copy them one-by-one. BTW I'm not saying that there's definitely no way to do what you want with `aws s3 cp --recursive`, but I'm not aware of one that supports contracting the source key prefix.

Comment: @jarmod- okay, Thanks! Is it possible that you can share a sample script that greps only .txt files from a s3 bucket and its subfolders and copies those to another s3 bucket?